# PHP - Grab file from folder, only part of name

Tags: php, csv, fopen

I have a folder called `/attachments`, where I store **one** csv file. However, that csv file is added dynamically, and therefore I don't know it's exact name. I only know that it will always be a .csv file that will start with "stocklist" (for example: `stocklist2141.csv` or `stocklist8281.csv`)

How can I "grab" that file using PHP? Right now, I've only been able to find a function for opening a file, where you know the filename:

```
$filepath = "./includes/api/inventory/attachment/test.csv";
$file = fopen($filepath, "r");
```

Comment: take a look at glob `http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php` or other similar functions to list files in a folder. Then use that to create your path for fopen

Comment: In `glob` expression you can also use something like only CSV files, e.g. `glob($path . '*.csv')` or more fitting for your purposes `glob($filepath . 'stocklist*.xls')`.

Comment: @TobiasF: but glob just returns Array back to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

The following example retrieves the files with extension .csv in the folder ./files:

```
//Get all CSV files in folder
$files = glob("./files/*.csv");

foreach($files as $file) {
    //Do interesting stuff with the file.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$files = scandir("./includes/api/inventory/attachment");
if (!empty($files)) {
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    // do stuff with $file
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = "./includes/api/inventory/attachment/";
// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```